# Why wasn't Avro Arrow program revived ever?

Tags: fighter, canada

When Canadians realized that it was a mistake to abandon their jet fighter program, why didn't they revive it?

Why wasn't Avro Arrow program revived ever?

Answer (score 6):

Since I'm not and was never a member of the Canadian Parliament or Canadian military top brass, this is pure speculation as you are likely to get from practically anyone else on this site with the possible exception of Rhino Driver (who is AFAICT a serving U.S. naval aviator).

My guess is that the Canadians looked to their south, saw one of their nation's staunchest allies who also happened to be one of the two remaining superpowers after World War II, and concluded that they couldn't afford to compete in the Cold War arms race but could definitely afford to profit from our R&D. Canada and the U.S. formed NORAD in 1958 as a joint venture to defend North American airspace, so Canada knew the U.S. had its back. Canada, for its part, spent its defense dollars outfitting defensive SAM and ICBM-intercept fortifications along probable Soviet nuclear bomber routes, effectively forming the northern part of the North American nuclear shield.

As far as not reviving Avro Canada now, the biggest answer is that Canada is so far behind the major powers in domestic aerospace technology that it would essentially have to recruit in the U.S. military-industrial complex anyway. In addition, compared to the USAF, the RCAF is *tiny*, composed mainly of transports to move the Army around, with just 70-odd CF-18 fighters making up the total fixed-wing combat complement, and a handful of ASW helicopters seeing service at naval stations and on the Canadian Navy's dozen Halifax-class frigates. In short, Canada has no real need for a domestic military aerospace program, as demand is very low and it can get all it wants from its southern neighbor at preferential prices. They're in line, IIRC, for a shipment of F-35s once Lockheed gets the bugs worked out.

**EDIT FROM COMMENT:** The comment says that Canada could build planes primarily for export. Such an effort would be doomed to fail for three reasons:

- The RCAF itself, given its small size and its outstanding relations with the U.S., would be unlikely to buy the planes. When looking for export buyers, your best marketing is the success of your design in your home country's military, so not having your military use the design at all is a big black mark (the F-5 is the only fighter I can think of that managed decent export success despite the U.S. never widely adopting it; even then, the USAF did have some test deployments of F-5 squadrons in Vietnam for the primary purpose of giving Northrop their backing to market the plane for export).

  This presents a Catch-22 for financing and R&D efforts; you're unlikely to get the funds to start working on a plane without any acknowledged demand for it, and with the Canadian aerospace industry being dormant for over almost 60 years, you're unlikely to generate demand for an as-yet nonexistent fighter from an unproven design team. So you have to get the money to build the fighter, and you have to build the fighter to get the money.
- Again, the Canadian aerospace industry is dormant, and therefore way behind the times. A joint venture with U.S. or European firms to provide a knowledge transfer to home-grown aerospace engineers seems like the only option to develop something new, when those same firms would then have to openly compete with the resulting firm and its designs. A new Canadian aerospace company would be reduced, as I said, to sniping U.S. talent to jump-start design work.
- Some countries that formerly imported jets are starting to look toward domestic production, making a primary export strategy that much more unappealing. Pakistan is the foremost example; their political relationship with practically all the major exporting countries is pretty shaky, and designs still in production for export are getting really expensive, so they're designing the J-17 jointly with China to have an inexpensive, capable fighter they can build in-house without relying long-term on imports. The resulting fighter (an interesting combination of design features from the F-16, F-18, and European designs like the Gripen and Rafale), on paper, is about 40 years behind the times, comparable to Gen-4 and 4.5 fighters like the F-15, F-16, MiG-29, Su-27, Typhoon and Rafale. But, the J-17 is projected to have a flyaway cost of only about \$15 milion a plane, which is a bargain compared to the aforementioned export choices, which start at about \$40 mil per plane and go up to \$110 mil.

Comment: @BROY In general, Canada wouldn't likely export to anyone that the U.S. wouldn't export to and, as mentioned by Keith, would be face a very tough battle competing with the U.S. (not to mention European) designs. It would be unlikely to be profitable.

Comment: "is about 40 years behind the times, comparable to Gen-4 and 4.5 fighters like the F-15, F-16, MiG-29, Su-27"  ---- I don't think so. Please give some references in favor of your statement.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the Wikipedia article clearly states that :

> Not long after the 1958 start of its flight test program, the
>   development of the Arrow (including its Orenda Iroquois jet engines)
>   was abruptly halted before the project review had taken place,
>   sparking a long and bitter political debate.The
>   controversy engendered by the cancellation and subsequent destruction
>   of the aircraft in production remains a topic for debate among
>   historians, political observers and industry pundits. "

But later in the article a comprehensive paragraph goes on to add:

> From 1953, some senior Canadian military officials at the Chief of
>   Staffs began to question the program. In June 1957, when
>   the governing Liberals lost the federal election and a Progressive
>   Conservative government under John Diefenbaker took power, the
>   aircraft's prospects began to noticeably change. Diefenbaker, from the
>   Canadian west, had campaigned on a platform of reining in what the
>   Conservatives claimed was "rampant Liberal spending". The Arrow was
>   not the only major industrial project targeted during the campaign;
>   others such as the "million dollar monster" postal-sorting computer
>   from Ferranti Canada were also singled out for political scorn. A
>   criticism that had been voiced in the 1950s in the media was that Avro
>   Canada as a company had little interest in competing with its products
>   in the market, and instead had come to rely solely upon the
>   availability of government financing for its activities.
>   Nonetheless, by 1958, the parent company had become Canada's third
>   largest business enterprise and had primary interests in rolling
>   stock, steel and coal, electronics and aviation with 39 different
>   companies under the A. V. Roe Canada banner.
>
> In August 1957, the Diefenbaker government signed the NORAD (North
>   American Air Defense) Agreement with the United States,
>   making Canada a partner with American command and control. The USAF
>   was in the process of completely automating their air defence system
>   with the SAGE project, and offered Canada the opportunity to share
>   this sensitive information for the air defence of North America.
>   One aspect of the SAGE system was the Bomarc nuclear-tipped
>   anti-aircraft missile. This led to studies on basing Bomarcs in Canada
>   in order to push the line further north, even though the deployment
>   was found to be extremely costly.

```
 The introduction of SAGE in Canada will cost around `$107 million`. Further improvements are required in the radar... NORAD has also recommended the introduction of the Bomarc missile... will be a further commitment of `$164 million`... All these commitments coming at this particular time... will tend to increase our defence budget by as much as `25 to 30%`.

    — George Pearkes, then-Minister of National Defence, 1958[67]
```

> Defence against ballistic missiles was also becoming a priority. The
>   existence of Sputnik had also raised the spectre of attack from space,
>   and, as the year progressed, word of a "missile gap" began spreading.
>   An American brief of the meeting with Pearkes records that Pearkes
>   "stated that the problem of developing a defence against missiles
>   while at the same time completing and rounding out defence measures
>   against manned bombers posed a serious problem for Canada from the
>   point of view of expense". It is also said Canada could afford the
>   Arrow or Bomarc/SAGE, but not both.
>
> By 11 August 1958, Pearkes requested cancellation of the Arrow, but
>   the Cabinet Defence Committee (CDC) refused. Pearkes tabled it again
>   in September, and recommended installation of the Bomarc missile
>   system. The latter was accepted but, again, the CDC refused to cancel
>   the entire Arrow program. The CDC wanted to wait until a major review
>   in 31 March 1959. They cancelled the Sparrow/Astra system in September
>   1958. Efforts to continue the program through cost-sharing with other countries were then explored.

```
We did not cancel the CF-105 because there was no bomber threat, but because there was a lesser threat and we got the Bomarc in lieu of more airplanes to look after this.

— George Pearkes, then-Minister of National Defence, 1959
```